# QueryDSL filtering on set

Tags: java, querydsl

Im having trouble using QueryDSL to filter with the below entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "newidea")
@Cacheable(true)
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
public class NewIdea extends DomainObject implements Membership {

    //id, other attributes etc

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "key.idea", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @QueryInit("newIdeaParticipations.key.student")
    private Set<NewIdeaParticipation> newIdeaParticipations = new HashSet<NewIdeaParticipation>();

    //constructor, getters, setters etc

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "newidea_student")
@AssociationOverrides({
        @AssociationOverride(name = "key.student", 
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id")),
        @AssociationOverride(name = "key.idea", 
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "idea_id")) })
public class NewIdeaParticipation implements Serializable {

    @EmbeddedId
    @QueryInit("student")
    private NewIdeaParticipationId key = new NewIdeaParticipationId();

    //other attributes, constructor, getters, setters etc

}

@Embeddable
public class NewIdeaParticipationId implements Serializable {

    @ManyToOne
    private Student student;

    @ManyToOne
    private NewIdea idea;

}
```

The filters:

```
    private BooleanExpression authorFilter(Student author){
//        return QNewIdea.newIdea.newIdeaParticipations.any().key.student.eq(author); //NPE any is not null, but any.students attributes is null, and any.key.student is null
//        return QNewIdea.newIdea.newIdeaParticipations.any().user.eq(author.getUser()); //hibernate.QueryException (any is null)
    }
```

Top query exception:

http://pastebin.com/Vr8gxM7P

Bottom query exception:

http://pastebin.com/sdjMJcmx

What am I doing wrong? Am I missing something?

Comment: The set is annotated with QueryInit. We've tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After updating to QueryDSL 3.2.3 the issue has been resolved and the below code works. (note the lack of @QueryInit annotations)

```
//idea class
public class NewIdea extends DomainObject implements Membership {
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "key.idea", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<NewIdeaParticipation> newIdeaParticipations = new HashSet<NewIdeaParticipation>();
}

//participation class
@Entity
@Table(name = "newidea_student")
@AssociationOverrides({
        @AssociationOverride(name = "key.student",
                joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id")),
        @AssociationOverride(name = "key.idea",
                joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "idea_id")) })
public class NewIdeaParticipation implements Serializable {
    @EmbeddedId
    private NewIdeaParticipationId key = new NewIdeaParticipationId();
}

//id class
@Embeddable
public class NewIdeaParticipationId implements Serializable {
    @ManyToOne
    private Student student;
    @ManyToOne
    private NewIdea idea;
}

//student class
public class Student extends Role {
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "key.student", cascade=CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true)
    private Set<NewIdeaParticipation> newIdeaParticipations = new HashSet<NewIdeaParticipation>();
}

//the filter
private BooleanExpression authorFilter(Student author) {
    return QNewIdea.newIdea.newIdeaParticipations.any().key.student.eq(author);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The top query exception is caused by Querydsl's limited path initialization.

The path initialization is documented here http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/3.2.2/reference/html/ch03s03.html#d0e1831

Concerning the second exception: Is the user property properly mapped?

Comment: Cheers @Timo for you input,

The set is annotated with QueryInit. We've tried annotating it with newIdeaParticipations.key.student, newIdeaParticipations.student, key.student, key and student with no success. A weird thing is that QNewIdea.newIdea.newIdeaParticipations.any() will sometimes be null, and sometimes not (running the same code). When its not null, its key.student will be null.

Lets ignore the second query for now as it was just put there for experimenting.

Comment: Ok, then this might be a bug as well. Feel free to file a ticket for it.

Comment: OK cool, just did: https://github.com/mysema/querydsl/issues/482 Thank you so much for your feedback and great work with QueryDSL!