# QueryDSL and Embadded class->wrong sql

Tags: querydsl

I'm trying to build sql query like this using querydsl.

```
SELECT i.id,i.owner_id FROM Invoice i WHERE i.id=1 AND i.Owner_id=2
```

where **i.id** and **i.owner_id**  is compound primary key.

I have two classes:

```
import javax.persistence.Embeddable;
import javax.persistence.Column;

@Embeddable
public class IDsClass
{
  ... public get and set ...

  @Column(name = "Id", nullable = false)
  private int ID;

  @Column(name = "Owner_Id", nullable = false)
  private int OwnerId;

  @Column( name="State")
  private int State;

}
```

and

```
import javax.persistence.*;
import core.IDsClass;

@Entity
@Table(name="invo__ice")

public class INVOICE extends BusinessEntity
{
    @EmbeddedId
    private IDsClass Key;

...get ans set ...
}
```

Querydsl code looks:

```
query.from(qryInvoice)
     .where(qryInvoice.Key.OwnerId.eq(20)
            .and(qryInvoice.Key.ID.eq(1)))
            .setUseLiterals(true);
```

When I'm get sql string, it contans this:

```
from iNVOICE
where iNVOICE.Key.OwnerId = 20 
and iNVOICE.Key.ID = 1
```

So, questions are:

1) What is wrong?

2) Why anotation @Table(name="invo__ice") didn't change table name in sql string?

Thanks.

Comment: Which query class do you use?

Comment: I used SQLQuery instead JPASQLQuery. Now annotations works.

Comment: I found that I have to use @AssociationOverrides to override composite key.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18347770/querydsl-filtering-on-set/  here I see how it's used, but I steel didn't get goal...   Can  any one help me?